# Is there a way to upload non-spatial lookup tables in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I have a lookup table that only has 4 columns (bool, date, number, string) with 9,998,081 rows.

The CSV is relatively small (285mb), but it "blows up" when I upload it to CartoDB, I suspect, because of the other columns that CartoDB adds (the_geom, created_at, updated_at, etc).

It eats up the quota of my account and the table becomes 819.62 MB.

Would it be possible to tell CartoDB that this is just a lookup table that I'll use in joins, and I won't need these extra columns?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where datasets in CartoDB would double or triple in size. The solution was to run the command `VACUUM FULL <tablename>;` in the SQL console.

https://twitter.com/juanignaciosl/status/561059817469775873